# Is there a way to add ports to tomcat at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to add a port to tomcat at runtime. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way to listen on all ports? I'm using spring and I want the user to be able to add call an API endpoint to add a new port to listen on.

I know that you can add additional ports in the config file, but I don't know what ports I will need to add.

```
@RequestMapping("/port/{port}")
void setPort(@PathVariable("port") int port){
    //add new tomcat port to listen on
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort; that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: Why? What is the point of the web server serving exactly the same content on different ports?

Comment: This is going to emulate multiple services and I want to separate them by port. I won't know how many or what they are until runtime.

Comment: Probably possible, but you'll have to deal with connectors, valves, ... You can have a look at https://howtodoinjava.com/tomcat/tomcats-architecture-and-server-xml-configuration-tutorial/ to understand some of Tomcat basics concept. But I think it will be a long and hard job.

Comment: Probably a better idea to look at a simpler server, like grizzly (https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/) that is the server of jersey, or even directly netty (https://netty.io/).

Comment: the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491231

Answer (score -1):

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements
  WebServerFactoryCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory container) {
        container.setPort(8083);
    }
}
```